How to install facebook watchman on Mac Catalina 10.15.5
Please I am installing watchman for so that I can setup my React Native environment on MacBook Pro early 11 with Catalina 10.15.5.
All efforts to successfully install watchman has been abortive. Could anyone please help me? I have tried the command “brew install watchman” but it would complain of Folly and C.make during the installation. I have tried to install watchman through MacPort using the following MacPort documentation…
1. unzip watchman-*-linux.zip
2. cd watchman-vYYYY.MM.DD.00-linux
3. sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/{bin,lib} /usr/local/var/run/watchman
4. sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
5. sudo cp lib/* /usr/local/lib
6. sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/watchman
7. sudo chmod 2777 /usr/local/var/run/watchman

The step 4 AND 5 are wrong in the above step as the terminal showed that bin/* and lib/* are wrong and there I am stuck.
Is there anyone who can give me a practical proven guide on installing watchman on Mac Catalina 10.15.5 through Homebrew or MacPort?
I appreciate your efforts in advance

Welcome to Ask Different.  Steps 2 and 3 look like they require you to change them after understanding the intent. Did you paste them in order without any changes?

MacPorts reports watchman does not work with Catalina. See here. Also, it probably does help that the MacBook Pro early 2011 model does not officially support macOS Catalina.
